# What is the fastest/better way to localize a .Net Compact Framework application?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I am developing an application for a Windows CE OS.

I am using .Net Compact Framework 3.5.

I want to localize my control texts on my form , and I am looking for the fastest way and compatible to compact framework using C#.

Please guide me with your valuable ideas how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

Usually if you just place all your "UI strings" into a resources.resx you can then generate a different resx for each culture en-GB or en-US or fr-FR for example. A rough overview can be found [here](http://sharpertutorials.com/localising-applications/) although there are probably better resources to be found on Google.

Basically the premise is that the user will set the device to their own culture (for example fr-FR for French) and then when your app loads if there are .resx files for fr-FR these will be loaded instead.

A couple of issues to be aware of:

- To manage these strings effectively it's best to wrap them all into a base .dll. This means you need to edit the tool that generates the code. By default it lists the resources as internal and you need these to be public instead. Otherwise you end up with a number of .resx files all over the place which is hard to manage.
- It's all or nothing. So if you want someone to have french text when they set their culture this will modify all items pertaining to the culture including formatting and clock orientation
- You CANNOT change the culture on WinCE at run-time. So if you have an app that needs to change cultures (as I once did with a bus application that moved between Ireland and Northern Ireland) then using .resx is no good at all and you have to roll your own system.

The other option is to roll your own localisation.

If you are going to be providing extensive culture specific localisation then consider your formatting of dates, currencies and text comparisons. Read up on the [Turkey test](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html) to see what kind of things you need to bear in mind.

Comment: You can have you app change cultures, you just can't react to to OS changing locales (well that's not totally true eitehr).  For example, you can have a way in the app itself to select the language and change the resx you pull from based on that selection.  Some day I should blog the details about how I do this (and without mucking with the resx generator tool too!)